# What technology to learn additional to PHP, MySQL, JS, HTML, CSS

Tags: python, ruby, perl, node.js, clojure

So i'm here and i pretty much got a full chain of languages for prette much any purpose:

- PHP
- HTML
- Javascript
- Java
- CSS
- SQL

And now i'm questioning what i should do next as an alternative or addition.

**I know there isn't a single best language but i hope i can at least get some expertise on what to expect from people using the languages.**

My main focus is in web development so mainly there are some technologies that are growing big really fast lately:

- node.js (yes basically javascript but i think theres a lot to learn for js to be used on the server side)
- ruby
- clojure

And there are some that have been around for quite some years now:

- perl
- python

But those are only the ones i've seen so far. What are your recommendations from these languages/technologies? Why? What are the benefits or have i missed the ultimate star among them all?

Comment: After learning python you probably don't want to use PHP anymore.

Comment: I think you forgot the "Reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)" technology

Comment: Yep but that's pretty much true for any language except maybe assembler... i'm looking to get some answers why a technology is worth adopting in comparison to the others.

Comment: You didn't tell us why you want to learn a new technology. Make more money? Get more productive? Get smarter? Just curious? Anyways, the question belongs to programmers, not here.

Comment: Well a bit of everything, i want to learn a new language so i have got a bigger repertoire of skills to choose from to solve a task. Wich will inherit some sort of better productivity as specific tasks differ in the requirements for the tools used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar "what language next" connundrum and picked Ruby. I read tons of Ruby vs Python articles, and finally decided to go through a simple app in each. I used Ruby on Rails and Python's Django Framework. I really liked the Rails MVC pattern usage. It helps me stick to better writing practices.
Also, I found a good IDE to use (RubyMine), which when you're using a tool all day, I find it helpful when getting to know a new Framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ultimate star each language has it's own pros and cons.
Most of the frameworks for the languages are almost the same and you can do pretty much all that you need with what you know. It all depends on your needs and current project.

I am a web developer that uses PHP and I still haven't had any problems except for maybe making a true Singleton like you can in Java for example (because of the lifespan of the script).

Python is cool I like it because it has many libraries and useful tools and the syntax is convenient.

I think that a good idea for you now would be to take on a MVC framework (Cohana, CodeIgniter, Yii etc...) and start using it and learn it because for more complex web applications experience with frameworks is good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn NoSql types of DB's and the design of NoSql Db's, as this is the way of the future for high traffic in depth web applications...

I would suggest doing some research in the design and implementation of:

Apache Hadoop
Cassandra
MongoDB
couchDB
BigTable

and perhaps even check out the wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

This is the "cloud" tech utilized by Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc. And it is pretty impressive but requires quite a deviation of approach as opposed to traditional databases (RDBMS)...

This is what was the natural progression for me, when I was hired at my current job to take my dev "skills" to the cloud :) (btw if you are good at nosql implementations, and call it "cloud" solutions you can make a lot more money, its an emerging market for mainstream consumers)

Comment: Yeah i thought about that too but on the other hand i'm nowhere near dealing with big data or to expect doing so at the moment. Also i find map&reduce very confusing :D